# How to replace only the pattern not replaced words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the characters while typing in the Textarea. But with the following code snippets (nearly 250 lines are there), here I'm using [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method of RegEx. It checks against the replacement too. I want it should check only the pattern/regexp.

**Test**

```
m -> A //ok
M -> B //ok
, -> F //Wrong, should be C
```

How can I get hte replacement without changing the order of hte line?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd HTML 4.0 transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
     
   </head>
   <body onload="javascript:formTest.source.focus()">
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         var text;
         
         function startConvert()
         {
         text = document.formTest.source.value;  
            
   text = text.replace(/\u006d/g, "A");
   text = text.replace(/M/g, "B");
   text = text.replace(/,/g, "C");
   text = text.replace(/</g, "D");
   text = text.replace(/c/g, "E");
   text = text.replace(/C/g, "F");
   text = text.replace(/v/g, "G");
   text = text.replace(/V/g, "H");
   text = text.replace(/I/g, "I");
   text = text.replace(/x/g, "J");
   text = text.replace(/X/g, "K");
   text = text.replace(/xs/g, "L");
   
   text = text.replace(/\//g, "@");
                    
         document.formTest.destination.value=text;
         }
         
            
      </script>
      <center>
         <table width="500" >
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <form name="formTest">
                     <td>        
      <textarea onkeyup="startConvert();" 
      onclick="startConvert();" 
      name="source" 
      rows="5" 
      onselect="startConvert();">
      </textarea>
     
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <textarea 
      name="destination" rows="5"></textarea>
                     </td>
                  </form>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a substring from an earlier `.replace` replaced with something that's being searched for in a later `.replace`, the result of the earlier `.replace` will be overwritten by the later one. I'd use an object of replacement values instead, with only a single `.replace`, so that no character gets checked and replaced more than once.

If the characters to match may be characters with a special meaning in a regex, like `[`, [escape them first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493):

```js
var text;
const replacements = {
  '\u006d': 'A',
  M: 'B',
  ',': 'C',
  '<': 'D',
  c: 'E',
  C: 'F',
  v: 'G',
  V: 'H',
  I: 'I',
  x: 'J',
  X: 'K',
  xs: 'L',
};
const pattern = new RegExp(
  Object.keys(replacements)
    .map(s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))
    .join('|'),
  'g'
);
function startConvert() {
  document.formTest.destination.value = document.formTest.source.value
    .replace(pattern, match => replacements[match]);
}
```

```html
<center>
  <table width="500">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <form name="formTest">
          <td>
            <textarea onkeyup="startConvert();" onclick="startConvert();" name="source" rows="5" onselect="startConvert();">
      </textarea>

          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea name="destination" rows="5"></textarea>
          </td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
```

Comment: Will this method useful to the rest of the lines?

Comment: What do you mean? It will replace a found character on any line.

Comment: Here, I posted only 13 lines to replace. But there're almost 300 lines to be replaced as this.

Comment: If you want to be able to transform that into an object quickly, you can use the method I used, with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zZuuax/1)

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't work for `text = text.replace(/n\[s/g, "ù--_ü");` and `text = text.replace(/N\[h/g, "ú_ô");` and `text = text.replace(/n\[h/g, "ù--_ô");`

Comment: If the characters to match may be characters with a special meaning in a regex, like `[`, [escape them first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493)

Comment: Replace the `\w`, which matches only word characters, with anything but a `"`, `[^"]+`

Comment: Thanks, https://pastebin.com/46z0HUiC is the entire list but got errors, please.

Comment: Add `'` delimiters around the key replacement so that the invalid characters like `\[` are parsed correctly: `'$1': '$2',`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking against the whole string,

```
var str = document.formTest.source.value; 
var text = str .substr(str .length - 1);
text = text.replace(/\u006d/g, "A");
...
```

This will do.

Comment: What about for multiple characters (string) ?

Comment: @testteam var text = str .substr(str .length - n);

Answer (score -2):

use onkeyup="functionName()",
remove onclick() and onselect()